# FIX engines comparison

Tags: quantlib, quantitative, fix, quants, quickfix

Need help, looking for some comparison between c++ FIX engines, like onixs, antenna and some fpga solutions. 
If anyone has experienced some of the named engines also would like to  hear the experience.

Comment: Is your application intended to be enterprise use?
I have worked with http://www.fix8.org/ which is C++.
But for the main part the projects I have worked on use java FIX engines.